# Change Behavior of controller based on calling element

Tags: angularjs

I have one controller used by two different views:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-include="slice = false">
    <span ng-repeat="value in values">{{ value }}</span>
</div>
...
<span ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="value in values">{{ value }}</div>
</span>
```

The controller:

```
var MyCtrl = function($scope){
    $scope.values =  ['a','fancy','array'];
    // if called from span
    //$scope.values =  ['a','fancy','array'].slice(2);
}
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to detect from what element the controller is being called to change the behavior of the controller.

*Update:* Based on @matys84pl's answer, here is my new controller

```
MenuCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.slice = true;
    if($scope.slice === false) { // wont go inside 
        $scope.data = ['a','fancy','array'];
    } else {
        $scope.data = ['a','fancy','array'].slice(2);
    }
    console.log($scope.slice); // still true for both
}
```

Comment: Have you thought using something like `$scope.otherValues =  $scope.values.slice(2);` and then, on the span element `<div ng-repeat="value in otherValues">{{ value }}</div>`?

Comment: actually the content in the elements is the same template so it has to be the same for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is that the controller should not be aware of the view... so you should instead pass something from the view to the controller using [ngInit](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit), like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span ng-repeat="value in values">{{ value }}</span>
</div>
...
<span ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="isDifferent = true">
    <div ng-repeat="value in values">{{ value }}</div>
</span>
```

and then check isDifferent value in the controller.

**Update:** A plunker with working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/zUgLSQcAaZX5j6JBoQAO

Comment: Thanks,it seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know about ng-init.

Comment: sorry it didn't work, maybe I'm missing something. Inside MyCtrl I use
console.log($scope.isDifferent) //-> gives undefined.  
Edit: just next to console.log($scope.isDifferent); I do console.log($scope) and $scope has isDifferent. Any Idea of the problem?

Comment: You have to define isDifferent first in your controller, like $scope.isDifferent = false

Comment: Also remember that each controller instance will have its own scope.

Comment: Hi, I've added a working example. Basically you cannot have a if condition in the body of the controller that checks the value that you will change with ng-init... the if will run when the new instance of controller is made, then the ng-init expression will be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" behavior=2>...
```

Please forgive my lazy js - I'm used to coffeescript

```
var MyCtrl = function($scope, $attrs){
    if $attrs.behavior != 2
        $scope.values =  ['a','fancy','array'];
    else
        $scope.values =  ['a','fancy','array'].slice(2);
}
```

I guess you could do something similar by swapping $attrs for $element and changing your test.